# python bootstrap.py file could not be opened successfully

Tags: python, bootstrapping, traceback

I'm following the instructions here: https://github.com/hackable-devices/makerbot_tools
to install makerbot drivers.

I get to the instruction to bootstrap the project. When I run

```
python bootstrap.py
```

My response is:

```
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.9.6.tar.gz
Extracting in c:\users\kevin lee jr\appdata\local\temp\tmpsd6_ga
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "bootstrap.py", line 92 in <module>
        ez['use_setuptools'](**setup_args)
    File "<string>", line 116, in use_setuptools
    File "<string>", line 101, in _do_download
    File "<string>", line 73, in _build_egg
    File "C:\Python27\lib\tarfile.py", line 1665, in open
        raise ReadError("file could not be opened successfully")
tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully
```

Any idea what the problem is with opening those files? I have the tarfile module installed.